# How do I trigger mousedown vs click event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, gmail

I am refactoring a small piece of code for adding a signature in the end of the email body, but I am struggling a bit with a javascript notion. 
Initially, the code was written like this:

```
$(document).off('mousedown').on('mousedown', function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('T-I-J3')) {
    //call insert signature method if gmail reply button is clicked
    self.mailAction.insertSignatureForFreeUsers("gmail-reply");
  }
});
```

and it works fine. 
I tried to refactorize the code as:

```
$(document).off('click','.T-I-J3').on('click','.T-I-J3', (event) => {
  //call insert signature method if gmail reply button is clicked
  self.mailAction.insertSignatureForFreeUsers("gmail-reply");
});
```

but it does not seem to work at all. Is there any reason for this different behavior?

Please, let me know if more context is needed.

Comment: Why not simply `$('.T-I-J3').off('click').on('click', event => { mailAction.insertSignatureForFreeUsers('gmail-reply'); });`?

Comment: @PHPglue probably because it is dynamic....

Comment: Is the click called? reason you are not doing mousedown now?